# Modularized XML files and nested procedures

Tags: xml, xslt, transclusion

Most of the programming languages out there have some form of [include directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_directive). C has `#include` macros, Python has `from-import-as`... following [this discussion on FreeCAD forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/writing/comments/b0ywcw/free_markdown_editors_with_live_preview_for/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x), I'm interested to know if there are any possibilities to have something like Pascal procedures, which do not return any values but run a piece of code given some variables, for XMLs or any of their flavors. I'm totally aware of the fact that XML is not a programing language, per se, but other markup languages have some form of include functionality (e.g., LaTeX, MultiMarkDown, AsciiDoc, reStructuredText. more info [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/writing/comments/b0ywcw/free_markdown_editors_with_live_preview_for/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)).

Fow example consider the `document.xml` I have attached [here](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=40029#p340360). It would be great if I could put the whole `<Object name="Box" Extensions="True">` tag in a different XML file and then import it with some parameters adjusting the placement:

```xml
<Property name="Placement" type="App::PropertyPlacement">
    <PropertyPlacement Px="0.0000000000000000" Py="0.0000000000000000" Pz="0.0000000000000000" Q0="0.0000000000000000" Q1="0.0000000000000000" Q2="0.0000000000000000" Q3="1.0000000000000000" A="0.0000000000000000" Ox="0.0000000000000000" Oy="0.0000000000000000" Oz="1.0000000000000000"/>
</Property>
```

something like `import with variables = ...`

I hope I have explained myself properly and have used correct tags. Otherwise please help me modify them.

Answer (score 1):

> Most of the programming languages out there have some form of include
>   directive. C has #include macros, Python has from-import-as...
>   following this discussion on FreeCAD forum, I'm interested to know if
>   there are any possibilities to have something like Pascal procedures,
>   which do not return any values but run a piece of code given some
>   variables, for XMLs or any of their flavors. I'm totally aware of the
>   fact that XML is not a programing language, per se, but other markup
>   languages have some form of include functionality (e.g., LaTeX,
>   MultiMarkDown, AsciiDoc, reStructuredText. more info here).

It seems that some of the requirements in this question are met and implemented by the **standard [W3C Xinclude specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude-11/)**.

In particular, do have a look at the examples at the end of the normative document:

**https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude-11/#examples**

There are several XInclude implementations: **[Saxon supports XInclude](https://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/sourcedocs/XInclude.html)** via the **[Xerces parser](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xinclude.html)**.

Another W3C standard -- XProc has an "**[XInclude step](https://www.w3.org/TR/xproc/#c.xinclude)**".

XInclude is also implemented as one of the results of the **[MVP-XML](http://mvp-xml.sourceforge.net/xinclude/)** project.

Comment: this is nice. so there is no need to use XSL-XSLT? That's what I have already proposed [here](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=40054#p340578).

Comment: @Foad Whether or not to use XSLT depends on the complexity of your requirements.